# Connecting to a server and grabbing the received buffer

Tags: c

My input is like this on a browser: 127.0.0.1:7777/fileName.txt

If I understand the connection correctly I will have something like this inside the recvBuff:

```
GET /filename.txt HTTP 1
```

I can't get the file name out of that recvBuff. What am I doing wrong below.

```
   while(1)
   {
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 
        while ((n = read(connfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0)
        {
         recvBuff[n] = 0;
         // ***** Here is the problem ***** //
         file_name = strchr(recvBuff, "/"); // trying to get the file name after the /
         printf(file_name);

         if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF)
             printf("\n Error : Fputs error\n");


         // Get the file and put into buffer the content of file.

         // send file
         write(connfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));

         close(connfd);
    } 

  close(connfd);
  sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: enable/check the compiler warnings.

Comment: Any idea why every time I run the code I need to change ports for the server? If I keep the same port I can't connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `strchr(recvBuff, "/")` to `strchr(recvBuff, '/')`

`strchr` expects a char argument, but `"/"` is a const char array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char recvBuff[] = "Lolkitten/test.html";
    char* file_name1 = strchr(recvBuff, "/");
    char* file_name2 = strchr(recvBuff, '/');
    printf("1: %s, 2: %s\n",file_name1,file_name2);
    return 0;
}
```

yields

```
1: (null), 2: /test.html
```

http://ideone.com/Q3N5CA

Comment: +1.  For completeness, should also read repeatedly until you find `\r\n` as `recv` doesn't guarantee to deliver an entire HTTP request in a single call.

Comment: well, it's far for complete, the filename ends at the space character, HTTP has its own encoding for filenames, script kiddies can send invalid requests, etc...

Comment: I end up doing something like adding '\0' at after the file name, so in essence I affect recvBuff, does that matter? `aFileName.txt\0` is what the variable char *file_name looks like after my parsing.